# Namespace with object literal

Tags: jquery, namespaces

After a good study on namespace, I've come to a conclusion that binding settings of a site into an object and accessing it on global level is much better for not polluting the global namespace.

But I would like to clarify on few things:

> 1) What's the difference between these two and which is better and
>   why? (Note the usage of keyword ***window*** in **exmp2**

**exmp1:**

```
 var namespace = (function(){
     var setting1: function(){
     },
     var setting2: function(){
     }

     return {
       test: setting1;
    };
    })();
```

**exmp 2:**

```
window.ckit = {
     setting1: function(){
     },
     setting2: function(){
     }
   };
```

2) Once the object is created so, I would like to further namespace it to avoid object name collision with other libraries. Everywhere online I found this is the way suggested in achieving it.

```
var namespace= namespace|| {};
```

As far as I can understand this checks if the namespace exist and if not creates new object? How can this help in avoiding the collision?

> What is the way to **re-namespace** the object namespace above into
>   any name that I like to be used **throughout my entire project**?

Do I need to re-namespace on every single page that's going to make use of the namespace? Or if can do it on the very first page that get loaded, how?

Comment: "_What's the difference between these two?_" The second examples works, the first not

Comment: In example 1, you should be using `var` and not object properties, because you didn't declare it as an object.

Comment: @Andreas, can explain further why the first doesn't because I've created one and I can access the properties like namespace.setting1 everywhere..

Comment: @4castle, sorry I overlooked it..in my real-code I did add var in front and it works. I just wanna which is better and how to re-namespace it?

Comment: Because the first is (still) a syntax error: https://jsfiddle.net/e1Lxsy2c/

Comment: Even if you [fix all the syntax errors](https://jsfiddle.net/tk5b4mqo/1/) in example 1, you still cannot reference them as `namespace.setting1`, because you didn't return anything from the IIFE, so `namespace` is undefined.

Comment: Guys forget the syntax errors, they're all fixed and runs well on my real-code but I just need to know difference between namespace using object and window.